# Solving $7^{k}\; \equiv\; 11\; \left( \mbox{mod}\; 26 \right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

How do you solve modular equations where the variable is in the exponent like:

$7^{k}\; \equiv\; 11\; \left( \mbox{mod}\; 26 \right)$

Do you have to use fermats little theorem or euler totient function or something of that sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inspection,  $\displaystyle7^2\equiv-3,7^3\equiv5\implies7^5\equiv-15\equiv11\pmod{26}\implies 7^k\equiv 7^5\iff 7^{k-5}\equiv1$

Now, $\displaystyle7^6\equiv25\equiv-1\implies7^{12}\equiv1\implies$ord$_{26}7=12$

$\displaystyle\implies 12|(k-5)\iff k\equiv5\pmod{12}$

---

Alternatively, observe that ord$\displaystyle_{26}7=12=\phi(26)\implies 7$ is a primitive root $\pmod{26}$

So applying [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) on $$7^k\equiv11\equiv7^5\pmod{26}$$

we get, $$k\equiv 5\pmod{\phi(26)}$$

Comment: One could also notice that since $26=13\cdot 2$ the Euler totient is $\phi(26)=(2-1)(13-1)=12$ so that $a^{12}\equiv 1\pmod {26}$ for all $a$ with $gcd(a,26)=1$.

Comment: @LutzL, can you please elaborate your method, how it helps to solve this problem?

Comment: It is just an insight to arrive faster at the partial result that the order of $7$ is a divisor of $12$. Or the observation that it is no coincidence that you arrived at the power 12. All your other computations are strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> *How do you solve modular equations where the variable is in the exponent?*

All you need to know is that there are only *n* possible remainders modulo *n*, so $a^x\text{mod }n$ can only have *n* possible outcomes, thus **inevitably generating a cycle** of length $\le n$. So all you need is just a bit of patience. And eventually a computer. :-)